# kernel source error on dahdi installation in centos

Tags: centos, kernel, asterisk, configure

Trying to install dahdi from the [link](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/05/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-centos-6/). I have downloaded package for dahdi. But on doing

```
cd /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete*
make && make install && make config
```

My terminal shows

```
[root@localhost dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0]# make
make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
You do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

output of uname -r

```
[root@localhost dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0+2.10.0]# uname -r
 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
```

I have the kernel source then why its showing the message
**You do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 kernel installed.**

I know this question is asked many times.I have tried those but dint resolve this problem.
I have tryed updating  my system but it says nothing to update.

Any Suggestions apart from reinstalling my OS???

Answer (score 1):

Sure this described everywhere. If you not want read, try this:

```
yum update -y
yum install kernel-devel -y
reboot
```

Comment: tryed that,it says nothing to do already updated that package

Comment: try reinstall kernel-devel

Comment: And make sure you reboot so that you're running the kernel that you installed the kernel-devel tools for (or run sudo yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) )

Comment: solved it, removed all kernel packages by `yum remove kernel*` and then reinstalling by `yum install kernel*`

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the source and found that it looks a different location .

First run

```
yum install kernel-devel
reboot
```

And here is the trick

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux /usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
```

For example in my server

> [root@freepbx ~]# ls -l /usr/src
>
> lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      34 Jul 12 17:31 linux -> kernels/3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

First update with YUM:

```
yum update
```

Install the kernel headers & kernel devel on CentOS / RHEL:

```
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

Reboot and attempt to rebuild Asterisk / DAHDI tools, if it still fails check your kernel version with:

```
uname -r
```

And then check the linked kernel source:

```
cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`
```

Check the symbolic link with:

```
ls -l
```

If the link is broken fix it with:

```
ln -s /usr/src/kernels/(kernel-source-dir) build
```

https://itgala.xyz/you-do-not-appear-to-have-the-sources-for-kernel-installed/